# Mongoose web server and IE9 browser

Tags: internet-explorer-9, mongoose-web-server

I am using mongoose(version 3.1) web server and my client consists of a html page which in turn includes *.js and *.css files. My web page works fine in Mozilla Firefox and Google chrome. But on IE9 it fails to open. First time it doesn't launch in IE and but on closing the browser and reopening it (without clearing the cache) second time the webpage launches. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose 3.1 is very old. Your issue might involve keep-alive logic in that version. Upgrade to a newer version and try it again. You also might try different settings on the keep-alive option. (see the docs for details on that option).